# Scraping a table for links, click links & scrape data

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a table which I wish to pick up all the links, go through the link and scrape the items within td class=horse.

The home page where the table is with all the links has the following code:

```
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-calendar">
    <tr>
        <th width="160">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=NSW">NSW</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=VIC">VIC</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=QLD">QLD</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=WA">WA</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=SA">SA</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=TAS">TAS</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=ACT">ACT</a></th>
        <th width="105"><a href="/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=NT">NT</a></th>
    </tr>  


    <tr class="rows">
        <td>
            <p><span>FRIDAY 13 JAN</span></p>
        </td>

                <td>
                    <p>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,NSW,Ballina">Ballina</a><br>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,NSW,Gosford">Gosford</a><br>

                    </p>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,VIC,Ararat">Ararat</a><br>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,VIC,Cranbourne">Cranbourne</a><br>

                    </p>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p>

                            <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,QLD,Doomben">Doomben</a><br>

                    </p>
                </td>
```

I currently have the code to look up the table and print the links

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#path to chromedriver 
path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/Kirsty/Downloads/chromedriver'

#ensure browser is set to Chrome 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= path_to_chromedriver)

#set browser to Racing Australia Home Page
url = 'http://www.racingaustralia.horse/'
r = requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

#looks up to find the table & prints link for each page
table = soup.find('table',attrs={"class" : "full-calendar"}). find_all('a')
 for link in table:
        print link.get('href')
```

Wondering if anyone can assist in how I can get the code to click on all the links that are within the table & do the following to the each of the pages

```
g data = soup.findall("td",{"class":"horse"})
for item in g_data:
   print item.text
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "Click on the links"? Meaning, going to the page of the link, then scraping all the links on there?

Comment: Yes, so the table consists of data such as the below,
   <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-calendar"> 
  <tr class="rows">
   <td><p><span>FRIDAY 13 JAN</span></p>
   </td><td><p>
<a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,NSW,Ballina">Ballina</a><br>
       
        <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,NSW,Gosford">Gosford</a><br>
       </p></td>
    <td><p>
      
<a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,VIC,Ararat">Ararat</a><br>
       
        <a href="/FreeFields/Form.aspx?Key=2017Jan13,VIC,Cranbourne">Cranbourne</a><br></p></td>

Comment: @KirstyDent Please put any relevant data, like the HTML in your comment above, into the question itself so that it's easier for later readers to find.

Comment: apolgies - I will do now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4, re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
start_url = 'http://www.racingaustralia.horse/'

def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_links(url):
    soup = make_soup(url)
    a_tags = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^/FreeFields/"))
    links = [urljoin(start_url, a['href'])for a in a_tags]  # convert relative url to absolute url
    return links

def get_tds(link):
    soup = make_soup(link)
    tds = soup.find_all('td',  class_="horse")
    if not tds:
        print(link, 'do not find hours tag')
    else:
        for td in tds:
            print(td.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links = get_links(start_url)
    for link in links:
        get_tds(link)
```

out:

```
http://www.racingaustralia.horse/FreeFields/GroupAndListedRaces.aspx do not find hours tag
http://www.racingaustralia.horse/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=NSW do not find hours tag
http://www.racingaustralia.horse/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=VIC do not find hours tag
http://www.racingaustralia.horse/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=QLD do not find hours tag
http://www.racingaustralia.horse/FreeFields/Calendar.aspx?State=WA do not find hours tag
.......

WEARETHECHAMPIONS 
STORMY HORIZON 
OUR RED JET 
SAPPER TOM 
MY COUSIN BOB 
ALL TOO HOT 
SAGA DEL MAR 
ZIGZOFF 
SASHAY AWAY 
SO SHE IS 
MILADY DUCHESS
```

bs4 + requests can meet your need.

Comment: how do you add pagination to this code? Where the main page has several pages